# Derivation of power transmitted in a wave

Tags: waves, string, power

In the derivation of power transmitted by a travelling wave, we consider only the force on the left side of the element which has been assumed. The force on the right side or the net force are not considered.

A possible explanation for this might be that we only need the power being delivered by the source. 
Then **what does the rate of work done due to the right force contribute to ?**

**Why are we not considering the right force?**

You can refer to this snapshot.

[image: The snapshot of what is written in the link i shared.]

[image]